# Do any major orthodox Trinitarian theologians or denominations hold that St. Paul was closer to a Biblical Unitarian than a Trinitarian?

Tags: trinity, paul-apostle, non-trinitarian, biblical-unitarian

Reading through St. Paul's letters, I come away with the impression St. Paul would have been comfortable as a contemporary Biblical Unitarian. For one example among many, consider Romans 8:34.

> "For Christ Jesus, who died, and more than that was raised to life, is
> at the right hand of God—and He is interceding for us."

Here you have God, Jesus to the right hand of God, and Jesus interceding between humans and God.

Counter to these sorts of passages are a few opaque passages where some argue St. Paul is claiming Jesus was God.

Are there any major orthodox (main branch Protestant, Catholic, or Orthodox) Christian theologians or denominations who hold that St. Paul was closer to a Biblical Unitarian than a Trinitarian?

Comment: How do you define 'Orthodox' ? And do you consider your own views to be 'Orthodox' ?

Comment: @NigelJ By lower-case 'o' orthodox I just mean Catholic, main branch Protestant, or Orthodox. So, this would not include JWs, Mormons, Christian Science followers, Unitarians, and various other groups I'm sure I could list if desired.

Comment: It certainly is unlikely that any mainstream trinitarian denomination would assert that Paul or any other Bible writer was ever anything less than 100% trinitarian.

Comment: Not necessarily. We recognise that the theology was developed over time, so the Biblical authors may not have fully understood all the implications of what they wrote. But to be closer to a Unitarian than a Trinitarian would mean being closer to Jesus being non divine than divine, and that's pretty untenable.

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/56275/23657

Comment: By saying, " I come away with the impression St. Paul would have been comfortable as a contemporary Biblical Unitarian. For one example..." you are using your personal opinion / interpretation as the basis of your question. Also shown by you saying there "are a few opaque passages where some argue St. Paul is claiming Jesus is God". This will lead answerers to respond with their opinions / interpretations.

Comment: I think an answer that elaborates on the comment by curiousdanni would be good. Trinitarians don’t believe that the theology was fully developed when Paul was alive. Restoration theology agrees with that concept.

Comment: Is it accurate to say that BU beliefs vary on Jesus having a pre existence? Some insisting he did not exist prior to being born of Mary, while others allow that Jesus existed as the created Son of God in heaven before coming to earth?   I don’t think Paul would have agreed with the thought that Jesus did not pre exist. @OneGod can you elaborate on which BU beliefs you think Paul would have been comfortable with?

Comment: David was not a unitarian. He knew 'The Lord' and he knew 'my Lord' and he said 'take not thy Holy Spirit from me'. But he did not _yet_ have the full revelation to accurately define these matters. Likewise, the early church. (I am pondering offering this comment as an answer.)

Comment: @Kris Yes, accurate. Biblical Unitarian basically is used to distinguish from what is now Universal Unitarians, who tend to de-emphasize the Bible in various ways. So BU's hold God isn't 'one substance but three persons' or something like that. There are patterns of belief among BU's but belief in pre-existence is somewhat tangential. However, my impression is most BU's don't hold to literal pre-existence, only notional.

Comment: @curiousdannii Like what Kris links to, it would only require Paul not believing Jesus was divine in a specific sense of 'divine'. Many Biblical Unitarians hold Jesus is divine in some important sense. A typical definition is "of or relating to a god, especially the Supreme Being." It's vague. Can easily include the Son of God who was conceived by the power of the Holy Spirit, is God's icon and representative, has been given all authority by God, and now rules at the right hand of God.

Comment: @Anne That's my impression and sets up motivation for posting the question. Not sure what the problem is with it.

Comment: @Anne ... except that I'm treading on Trinitarian toes. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Do any major orthodox Trinitarian theologians or denominations hold that St. Paul was closer to a Biblical Unitarian than a Trinitarian?**

If any theologian thought this then *who* would consider them to be a *major orthodox Trinitarian theologian*?  Surely not Trinitarians.

You say the passages arguing that Jesus is God are opaque:-

"*Counter to these sorts of passages are a few opaque passages where some argue St. Paul is claiming Jesus was God.*"

You want to restrict the subject to only Paul's beliefs.  Let me ask you how opaque do you consider these few passages to be:-

1. The Bible says "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth" (Gen 1:1).

The Apostle Paul says of our Lord Christ: "*All things* were created by him" (Col 1:16).

2. Paul himself wrote of God: "For of him, and through him, and to him, are all things, to whom be glory for ever" (Romans 11:36).

But of Christ he writes:  "Christ loved the church and gave himself for it, ... that he might present it *to himself* a glorious church" (Ephesians 5:25, 27).

3. The Psalmist says of God: "Whom have I in heaven but thee? And there is none upon earth I desire besides thee" (Psalm 73:25)

The Apostle Paul says: "For me to live is Christ" (Phil 1:21).  (What desire then is left for God, if Christ is not God?)

4. God says in the OT: "My son, give me your heart" (Prov 23:26)

But the Apostle Paul says: "I have espoused you to *one* husband, that I may present you as a chaste virgin to *Christ*" (2 Cor 12:2).  (Again, what love is left for God, if Christ is not God?)

5. God says in the OT: "Cursed be the man that trusts in man,  and makes flesh his arm, and whose heart departs from the LORD" (Jeremiah 17:5).

The Apostle Paul writes: "I know whom I have believed, and am persuaded that he is able to keep that which I have entrusted unto him against that day" (2 Tim 1:12).

6. Paul himself says: "God only wise" (Romans 16:27) i.e. only God is wise.

But Paul also writes of our Lord Jesus: "In whom are hid *all* the treasures of wisdom and knowledge" (Colossians 2:3).

I suspect that *inadequate views* of the altogether "otherness" of God himself - his glory, his holiness, his purity, his power, his eternity, and all his other characteristics in all their holiness - lie at the root of doubts about the divine nature of our Lord Jesus Christ.

As Charles Brown writes:

> "*When the Scriptures teach that there is one only God, the meaning will be found to be, not anything of this kind, that there is one Being immeasurably greater, wiser, better, than all others, *but* that there is one Being, besides whom there is in a sense none else at all, a Being of such a sole, unapproachable excellence, and glory in all things, in being and in all perfection, that **if you would bring any creature into comparison with him - it is a matter of indifference whether it be an archangel or a worm - He stands quite alone, in respect of both the one and the other alike**.*"
> (Charles Brown, "The Divine Glory of Christ", 1982, p25; first published 1868).

I believe this is the God of the Bible. And therefore I believe that where the Scriptures anywhere mention God and our Lord Jesus in the same breathe, as it were, then in such passages there is a clear declaration of the deity of our Lord Jesus Christ.  I mean in passages, of which the Scriptures are extremely full including the writings of the Apostle Paul, such as:-

"Grace be to you and peace from God our Father and from the Lord Jesus Christ" (Galatians 1:3).

This sort of mentioning of our Lord Jesus Christ in the same breathe as God the Father is really *blasphemy*, unless it is that Christ himself is truly God, the glorious Second Person of the Triune Godhead, sharing in that divine "otherness" which sets the Godhead **entirely alone from every creature, both worm and archangel alike**.

And so it is that whereas God has said in the Old Testament "I will not give my glory to another" (Isaiah 42:8) yet in the New Testament, Revelation 5:13, we read:

> "*Blessing, and honour, and glory, and power, be unto him that sits upon the throne* **and unto the Lamb** *for ever and ever.*"  Amen.

Comment: You pointed out that the OP wants "to restrict the subject to only Paul's beliefs." I would just add that Peter said "our beloved brother Paul" wrote "according to the wisdom given unto him" some things "hard to be understood, which they that are unlearned and unstable wrest, as they do also the other scriptures, unto their own destruction" (2 Peter 3:15-16). Perhaps lack of response to this Q is not due to Trinitarians feeling "their toes have been trodden on" [OPs comment], but to knowing the dangers inherent in this Q but, thankfully, you have answered it appropriately.

Comment: +1 for putting an answer forth, but it doesn't seem to be directed at the question, rather another question about Unitarian beliefs more generally. Of course all those passages quoted have responses from a BU viewpoint. "If any theologian thought this then who would consider them to be a major orthodox Trinitarian theologian? Surely not Trinitarians." Why not?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - Hi.  As you know, there is no where in the world a definitive list containing all the "major orthodox Trinitarian theologians".  And I think I _did_ answer the question by saying if some theologian somewhere _did_ think Paul was closer to a Biblical Unitarian than a trinitarian then he certainly would not figure on any such list as far as Trinitarians today are concerned. The closest person I can think of is not a major theologian but a major hymn writer, arguably the biggest of them all, Isaac Watts, who managed somehow to _upset both Unitarians & Trinitarians_ alike.

Comment: "Paul was closer to a Biblical Unitarian than a trinitarian then he certainly would not figure on any such list as far as Trinitarians today are concerned." OK, but that's what I asked about. Why do you think this?

Comment: Everyone who is Trinitarian sees the deity of Christ virtually everywhere in the writings of Paul and all the other writings of the NT.  It isn't just the "proof texts" such as "God was manifest in the flesh" (1 Tim 3:16) it is everywhere, as I tried to show in my answer.  If Jesus is not God then he is just a worm, a slightly longer, thicker or whiter worm, but in comparison to God just a worm.. yet he is praised and honoured and mentioned in the same breathe as God.. archangels would shrink from allowing themselves to be praised in such a way, yet Christ receives such praise willingly.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any major orthodox (main branch Protestant, Catholic, or Orthodox) Christian theologians or denominations who hold that St. Paul was closer to a Biblical Unitarian? As Andrew Shanks notes, "If any theologian thought this then who would consider them to be a major orthodox Trinitarian theologian? Surely not Trinitarians."

However, if this question is approached from a broader religious perspective, then it is accurate to say Paul was once a Biblical Unitarian, insofar as that term might be applied at the time. This is a certainty, since Paul stated he was Jewish:

> “I am indeed a Jew, born in Tarsus of Cilicia, but brought up in this city at the feet of Gamaliel, taught according to the strictness of our fathers’ law, and was zealous toward God as you all are today. (Acts 22:3 NKJV)

Since Paul was Jewish, he should hold to the belief there is one one God, the Father.

If this is true why would he make any reference, "opaque" or otherwise, to the deity of Jesus? In fact, if this question arose, why would someone who believed there was only one God, the Father, not settle the matter by making an explicit statement of the singular deity in which they believed? The logical answer is Paul's Christian experience convinced him Jewish monotheism failed to accurately understand the nature of God. In other words, "One God the Father" did not correctly describe the God in which he came to believe in.

This is evidenced in the events in Athens as reported in Acts:

> <sup>16</sup> Now while Paul waited for them at Athens, his spirit was provoked within him when he saw that the city was given over to idols. <sup>17</sup> Therefore he reasoned in the synagogue with the Jews and with the *Gentile* worshipers, and in the marketplace daily with those who happened to be there. <sup>18</sup> Then certain Epicurean and Stoic philosophers encountered him. And some said, “What does this babbler want to say?” Others said, “He seems to be a proclaimer of foreign gods,” because he preached to them Jesus and the resurrection.
> (Acts 17)

Regardless of the exact nature of what the Epicurean and Stoic philosophers understood about Paul's message, it was not one of monotheism. Rather, as the text states, they understood Paul's message about Jesus and the resurrection as one which proclaimed foreign "gods" (plural).

Nor could Paul have proclaimed the God of Israel to them:

> <sup>19</sup> And they took him and brought him to the Areopagus, saying, “May we know what this new doctrine is of which you speak? <sup>20</sup> For you are bringing some strange things to our ears. Therefore we want to know what these things mean.” <sup>21</sup> For all the Athenians and the foreigners who were there spent their time in nothing else but either to tell or to hear some new thing.
> <sup>22</sup> Then Paul stood in the midst of the Areopagus and said, “Men of Athens, I perceive that in all things you are very religious; <sup>23</sup> for as I was passing through and considering the objects of your worship, I even found an altar with this inscription: TO THE UNKNOWN GOD. Therefore, the One whom you worship without knowing, Him I proclaim to you: (Acts 17)

The Athenians knew about the God of Israel, so it would be wrong to understand Paul explained the God of Israel was "THE UNKOWN GOD."

The events in Athens show Paul's message there was incompatible with monotheism as it was understood in Second Temple Judaism.

Comment: +1 for putting forth an answer. "it is accurate to say Paul was once a Biblical Unitarian. This is a certainty, since Paul was Jewish" This seems to suggest a misunderstanding of what Biblical Unitarianism is. It is not Judaism. Nor is it pre-Christ 1st C Judaism, of whatever variant you'd like. It fully engages with the New Testament, agrees Jesus is the Messiah, Son of God, and King ruling at the right hand of the Father, and agrees there is a New Covenant to replace the Old. It is emphatically *not* what Saul was.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Thank you. I was addressing the central issue of your question which is the difference between one God, the Father, and that of the Trinity. There is no way to reconcile what Paul proclaimed in Athens with the idea he held to the  belief there is but one God, the Father, who, in Biblical terms, is the God of Israel.

Comment: "There is no way to reconcile what Paul proclaimed in Athens with the idea he held to the belief there is but one God, the Father, who, in Biblical terms, is the God of Israel." I have gone back and read Acts 17:24-34. St. Paul is describing a God who a conventional Jew would have *no problem with* except when Paul talks about Jesus being the Messiah! Indeed, he describes Jesus as "the man [God] has appointed"!

Comment: Again, *the man*.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather 1) The Greek philosophers understood Paul proclaimed "foreign gods."  The word is plural. 2) Paul said he would explain the God which they did not know. And it is clear from both the New Testament and extra-Biblical sources, that the God of the Jewish people was well know to the Greeks.

Comment: The *Greeks* thought he was proclaiming 'foreign gods', whatever that might mean. That claim is clarified in the *very next sentence* - "They said this because Paul was proclaiming the good news of Jesus and the resurrection." As Paul himself then goes on to say, Jesus is a man appointed by God, and we have proof of this because of the resurrection. *Not* that we have proof Jesus is God (!) because of the resurrection!

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I believe the passage is quite clear. The Greek philosophers understood Paul was saying Jesus was both God and man, as Trinitarians hold. Obviously Paul is not proclaiming any form of monotheism. Nor is his message consistent with Judaism of the Diaspora because the God of what is now called the OT was in fact known to the Greeks: He could not be called "the Unknown God." OTOH, Jesus was not known to them and He is the God which they did not know, until Paul proclaimed Him.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather "....and declared to be the Son of God with power according to the Spirit of holiness, by the resurrection from the dead." (Romans 1:4) No one who is Jewish at that time would believe **the** Son of God was not fully God; just as one who was a son of Abraham was fully Jewish.

Comment: You're trying to infer a psychological state in anonymous 'Greek philosophers' in order to say St. Paul definitely believed Jesus was God? Seems dubious. But the more straightforward reading of what Paul is doing to me is quite different. These Greeks *already* worshipped (had a shrine to) the unknown God. He is then tying that sentiment to the Jewish God. Turns out, the unknown God they already worship is the Jewish God. He is not saying that God is Jesus! This is obvious from the passage immediately following in Acts. God - the unknown God - ...

Comment: ... is distinguished from Jesus, who is a man appointed by God. But you do have a point. The Greeks already had many gods, and they might indeed have thought of Jesus as a god, which Jesus himself does when comparing himself to the judges who were 'gods' in Psalm 82. The judges in Psalm 82 aren't God, though. Paul wouldn't have made that mistake either, IMO.

Comment: "No one who is Jewish at that time would believe the Son of God was not fully God" Can you say more? How do you know this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133322/discussion-between-revelation-lad-and-one-god-the-father).